# overloading member function from outside the class

Tags: c++, boost, struct, overloading

I'm writing a file handling system (using boost's property tree). I'm trying to make it simple to use and extend, as it is always a big time sink to develop a file system for every new project.

I've got it working for the most part. I can call add_data("meta.timeinfo","date","10/12/13") to add 10/12/13 to the date key under the timeinfo node which is nested in the meta node. I can also call add_data("meta.timeinfo","date",date_created) to write the value from that same variable into a string. I've got it set up that it'll treat all non-vectors the same, as well as all vectors the same.

My problem comes when I want to extend it to work with a struct. I want to oveload the add_data and get_data functions from inside the struct's file (I'm going to compile the base system as a library.) When overloading opperators, you usually just do something like this:

```
    void LBUtil::data_holder::add_data(std::string section, std::string key, tile_template data)
{
    if(section != "") section += ".";
    std::string sectionKey = section+key+".";

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"ID", data.ID);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"xPos", data.xPos);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"yPos", data.yPos);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"height", data.height);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"width", data.width);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"depth", data.depth);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"friction", data.friction);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"water", data.water);
};
```

But when I try and do that, I get the following error:

> error C2511: 'void
>   LBUtil::data_holder::add_data(std::string,std::string,tile_template)'
>   : overloaded member function not found in 'LBUtil::data_holder'

In case it'll help, my code for the data_holder class is as follows

```
#ifndef _LBUTIL_FILESYSTEM_DATA_HOLDER_H
#define _LBUTIL_FILESYSTEM_DATA_HOLDER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace LBUtil
{
    class data_holder
    {
        friend class file_holder;

    public:
        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        void add_data(std::string section, std::string key, DATA_TYPE data)
        {
            if(section != "") section += ".";
            propertyTree.put(section + key, data);
        };

        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        void add_data(std::string section, std::string key, std::vector<DATA_TYPE> data)
        {
            if(section != "") section += ".";

            std::string sectionKey = section + key+".";
            remove_data(section,key);

            propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"count", data.size());

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                propertyTree.put(sectionKey+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i), data[i]);
            }
        };

        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        void get_data(std::string section, std::string key, DATA_TYPE &data)
        {
            get_key(section,key,data);
        };

        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        void get_data(std::string section, std::string key, std::vector<DATA_TYPE> &data)
        {
            if(section != "") section += ".";
            data.clear();

            unsigned int count = -1;
            std::string sectionKey = section + key+".";

            get_key(section+key,"count",count);

            if(count == -1) return;

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                DATA_TYPE element = propertyTree.get<DATA_TYPE>(sectionKey+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i));
                data.push_back(element);
            }
        };

        void data_holder::remove_data(std::string parent, std::string target)
        {
            if(target != "") propertyTree.get_child(parent).erase(target);
            else propertyTree.erase(parent);
        }

    protected:
        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        void get_key(std::string section, std::string key, DATA_TYPE& data)
        {
            if(section != "") section += ".";

            boost::optional<DATA_TYPE> value = propertyTree.get_optional<DATA_TYPE>(section+key);

            if(value) data = value.get();
        };

        boost::property_tree::ptree propertyTree;


    };
}

#endif
```

The struct I'm trying to extend the data_holder class with is as follows:

```
#ifndef _LBMOON_TEST_TILE_TEMPLATE_H
#define _LBMOON_TEST_TILE_TEMPLATE_H

struct tile_template
{
    int ID;

    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    int height;
    int width;

    int depth;

    float friction;
    bool water;
};

void LBUtil::data_holder::add_data(std::string section, std::string key, tile_template data)
{
    if(section != "") section += ".";
    std::string sectionKey = section+key+".";

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"ID", data.ID);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"xPos", data.xPos);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"yPos", data.yPos);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"height", data.height);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"width", data.width);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"depth", data.depth);

    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"friction", data.friction);
    propertyTree.put(sectionKey+"water", data.water);
};

#endif
```

Is there any way I can avoid having to deal with creating a child class in every project where I define all new versions of the add_data and get_data functions?

Comment: Could you not create a templated free function to replace `propertyTree.put(section + key, data);` in `add_data`, something along the lines of `template<typename DATA> void put(ptree propertyTree, string section, string key, DATA data) { propertyTree.put(section + key, data); }`, and then specialize this for new types?

Comment: That doesn't change the problem though. I can't overload the "put" function from outside the class. I want to be able to pass a struct as an argument. Because in the code I'm going to be working with, I'll be reading/writing vectors full of structs. So it'd make everything simpler if I could overload the member function from outside the class somehow.

Comment: that's why I said *free* function. Make "put" a free function, declared defined outside the class

Comment: Ah ok. I see what ya mean. I'll do that if another solution doesn't come up. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the free function. You can specialize `add_data` from outside the class: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2906ec93680badcf

Comment: @melak47, sweet! That was EXACTLY what I wanted to do. Never would have figured out sticking "template<>" before the function would do it on my own. I'd vote this as the correct answer if I could, but alas it is just a comment. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created a function definition without a function declaration in the class. That's one problem and probably the one giving you the compiler error. You would have to include a function declaration in the class definition for this to work. But I don't think that's your intent.

In C++, you can effectively "overload" the data type using templates but the only way to completely replace the body of the function is to make another class that derives from it and replaces that function. ( Operators are special.)

So you can do this:

```
   data_holder mMyDataHolder;
    tile_template data;
    data_holder.add_data(section, key, data);
```

which will pass in your new structure. But it won't change the behavior.

I think what would best suit your overall objectives is to make your entire class templated. That way you can declare the function you want to overload as virtual like so:

```
template <class DataType>
class MyClass
{
public:
  virtual int OverloadThis( DataType &dt)
  {
    return 0;
  }
};
//You can overload it like this:
class MyDerivedClass : public MyClass<int>
{
public:
  virtual int OverloadThis( int &dt )
  {
    return 1;
  }
};
//Or like this:
template <class DataType>
class MyDerivedClass2 : public MyClass<DataType>
{
public:
  virtual int OverloadThis( DataType &dt )
  {
    return 2;
  }
};
```

Technically the function doesn't have to be virtual. It will still overload BUT references to it from within the base class will invoke the base class's instance of the function NOT the derived class's instance of the function. (If you're used to java, you'll want to use virtual. You'll be more comfortable with how the inheritance works then.)

Comment: Since the class is going to handle more than one type of data per instance (a config file isn't going to only have integers), templating the class wouldn't work. And I'm trying to avoid making a child class to add handlers for the structs, as I'd rather not have to add a lot of code to every project to add the stuff in (in my older version of the file system, I did this. And I had to tell the child to call it's parents function if handling a data_type that it already knew about. It makes the code bloated)